# Conflictcs between versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" within Xamarin Forms 5 .NET6.0 Android Project

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package

I'm building a Xamarin Forms 5 app including an Android Project using VS 2022 Preview
All NuGet packages are up-to-date.

The project references another project which is using the NuGet Package `RestSharp`
Upon building I get the following Warning:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
        D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
            System.Numerics.Vectors
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\schodmi\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\schodmi\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll".
            C:\Users\schodmi\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
            C:\Users\schodmi\.nuget\packages\restsharp\107.3.0\lib\netstandard2.0\RestSharp.dll
            D:\Repos_Git\IrrigationSystem\MIS\MIS.Frontend.App\MIS.Frontend.App\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MIS.Frontend.App.dll   MIS.Frontend.App.Android
```

If I dereference the dependency project or uninstall `RestSharp` the warning disappears.
I've researched the problem for more than an hour but nobody seems to have a solution or even a reason to why this warning occurs.

Things I tried without success:

- Removing `System.Numerics` and `System.Numerics.Vectors` from the Android project and adding the NuGet package `System.Numerics.Vector`
- Installing VS 2022 Release
- Deleting bin/obj folders within the project

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.  Is it actually causing a problem?  If not, ignore it

Comment: It is not a problem (yet)., but it clutters my Error List and I don't know how to ignore it since it doesn't even have an Error Code...

Comment: You should be able to hide warning in the error list.

Comment: According to this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15046), it seems that this is a common issue in the xamarin.forms and has not been solved.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT please solve this. I don't agree w/ Jason IMO warning are errors and at least hide errors and warnings that may be important.